# Extract numbers out of text with inconcistant linebreaks

Tags: regex

I have text with 6 numbers typically stored in one line

```
SomeData\n0.00 0.00 0.00 31,570.07 0.00 31,570.07\nSomeData
SomeData\n0.00 0.00 0.00 485,007.24 0.00 485,007.24\nSomeData
```

This regex worked fine on it:

```
\n[0-9,.-]* [0-9,.-]* [0-9,.-]* [0-9,.-]* [0-9,.-]* [0-9,.-]*\n
```

I noticed that every once in a while I get this:

```
SomeData\n0.00 0.00 10,921,594\n.89\n-\n9,563,271.0\n6\n0.00 1,358,323.83\nSomeData
```

Note how the linebreaks are randomly inserted after a sign or between numbers as if the system stored the values without filtering linebreaks.

I am struggling to get this extracted. I tried various expressions but my more successful one was [0-9,.-]*[\n]{0,1}[0-9,.-]*[ ]{0,1} to match an individual number.

What expression can I use to match both variations of the number formats preferably already stripping out the inconstant line breaks?

**Update: Going with**
    [-\n]{0,2}[0-9,]+[\n.0-9]{3,4}[\n ]{0,1}
**Please let me know if I there's a better way**

Comment: You have to figure out why those "spurious" newlines are there, or at least identify a very distinct pattern whereby you can either ignore them or eliminate them. May be possible to "ignore" IFF the pattern of numbers is completely distinguishable regardless of newlines -- distinguishable from all other SomeData for instance.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. Most of the patterns are as listed. Currently having more success with [-\n]{0,2}[0-9,.]*[\n]*[0-9]*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to write an exact representation of what constitutes a number, so in your case `[-+]?[0-9]+[0-9,]*(?:\.[0-9]+)?` would do the trick. This helps, because then your search can know when a number starts and when one ends (because of rules like: a sign always is at the start a dot cannot appear multiple times, etc.). Then you want to match pairs of six delimited by either a new line or space so wrap it in a capture group and limit by 6: `(...[ \n]*){6,6}`. This helps because then the regex engine can figure out by backtracking what to consider a number by knowing how many it should match. Then you want to allow new lines in pretty much any position, so place the new line in each character group. You might also want to anchor the numbers on both sides, but this is not necessary, because now the regex engine will try to identify valid tuples of 6 numbers. End result is:

```
SomeData\n([-+]?[0-9\n]+[0-9,\n]*(?:\.[0-9\n]+)?[ \n]){6,6}SomeData
```

This will find tuples of 6 numbers no matter where the enters are. Here is an example: https://regex101.com/r/jD5nT8/1